# Identify a reboot

Tags: windows, winapi, boot

Is there any "Boot session ID" or (reliable) "Boot timestamp"? 
For an installation I need to detect that a scheduled reboot took place indeed.

I guess I could do a dummy `MoveFileEx()` with `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT`, but i did hope for something easier.

(We have to install a 3rd party package that sometimes behaves erratically after an repair/update. In that state, accessing the device may even lock up the system)

(Windows XP, Vista, 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Windows has the equivalent of "uptime". Here's more info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555737

As I understand it, this should tell you how long ago the system was booted. Will that information solve your problem?

Comment: That's a good start - I found an updated sample (haven't tried yet) here: http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2109755/Re-Not-working-on-Vista-Any-ideas-modified.aspx

Answer (score 4):

For things like this, WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) is often a good starting place. I know you can get current uptime directly through it, which may allow you to determine if a machine recently rebooted.

Here is a blog post with some code samples as well:
http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/09/07/how-can-i-tell-if-a-server-has-rebooted.aspx

Depending on your implementation language, you probably just want to pull out the query code from the vbscript.

Answer (score 1):

You could search the System event log for event 6009 from the EventLog source - this is the first event recorded after each reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer has already been given here: [Find out if computer rebooted since the last time my program ran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717916/find-out-if-computer-rebooted-since-the-last-time-my-program-ran)

That seems to be the simplest way. Use `GlobalFindAtom()` to see if it exists and create it, with `GlobalAddAtom()`, if it doesn't. It will persist beyond the execution of your program. If your application runs again, and sees that the atom exists, then then it isn't the first run since reboot.

If the computer is restarted, then the atom won't exist, indicating that this is the first run of your program since the reboot.